# How to get array from another class in Swift 5

Tags: swift, class

I have a problem with getting strings, arrays and functions from other class in swift and I couldn't find a clear answer for that.

On example I have main storyboard where I want to get value from function which is in another file

ViewController.swift

```
print(Us.username())
```

Users.swift

```
import Foundation


public class Us {

func username(){
     return "Bob" // on example
}

}
```

Comment: Side note, but the standard practice is for function names to start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unless your method `Username()` is static, you should call it by first creating an instance of class and then through it:

```
var instanceOfUs = Us() // create an instance here
instanceOfUs.Username() // and then call your method
```

or

```
Us().Username()
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Us: UIViewController {

 Struct Users { 

    static func username() { }
    static var array = [Any]()
    static var string: String = ""
 } 
}



 Class ViewController: UIViewController { 

   print(Us.Users.array)
   print(Us.Users.string)
   Us.Users.username()

  }
```